# openGL drawing lag: points vs line_strip

Tags: opengl, lag

I'm using openGL to draw some very large images(3200 x 4000 pixels). I don't have objects that are anywhere near that large individually, but I do have many irregular lines that span the width and height. I'm currently displaying the lines by drawing all of the points on them as individual vertices (I know that's kind of ridiculous but I'm grabbing all the lines using image processing in openCV and the best way for me to do that is create a set of all the pixels that make up the line). I'm using user commands to rotate the images and I'm getting really large lag between the user input and the updated display. Would it be faster to instead draw with GL_LINE_STRIP and use all of the pixels and verteices in the line? or should i just thin out the pixels and use less data?

Comment: Since there is no activity on your question yet, I suggest you clarify exactly what it is you are doing. I, and likely many other readers, do not really know what you are trying to do.

Comment: my question was actually answered already but thanks for the concern, for some reason the comments were deleted